Why do fine-tooth blades smoke more than other blades when cutting thicker wood?
I cut a mix of wood types on my ten inch table and mitre saws and seven inch circular saw.  When using a coarse blade (24 tpi) there is a bit more chipping on the materials, so when doing fine cuts e.g for flooring and for countertops I swapped out to a 62 tpi.  The flooring is about 1/2 inch thick and responds well. The countertops are 1 1/4" to 1 1/2" .. and the blades do much more smoking than cutting on them.  The same cut that would smoothly get done in a couple seconds takes 10x that long and makes a black smokey mess.  Also any plywood just goes like a diesel engine and takes ridiculously long to cut.  The behavior is similar across all of them - table, mitre, and circular saws so clearly it is  due to the blades, not the saws.
Why are the fine teeth blades behaving this way?  I would think they would take longer to cut but not this behavior.  I'd like to get a handle on it because it is a PITA to swap blades back and forth when I have concurrent needs for both types of cuts.  For now I obviously will need to ditch the fine tooth blades because my house smells like a diesel engine.

Speeds and Feeds, Wood Elf Edition :)


I cut a mix of wood types on my ten inch table and miter saws and seven inch circular saw...

Primarily because your blade speed is too fast.
Higher TPI blades simply cannot cut and rip as fast through material as lower TPI blades which have larger teeth and remove more material on a given pass which sort of can accommodate a higher rotational or reciprocating blade speed.
That and with any thicker material to be cut more of the blade is also immersed in the material--the cutting generates heat, the heat builds up in the blade buried in the material versus much less of it being exposed to air to cool (if it were 1/8" thick for example vs > 1").  Not to mention the type of material being a factor... mix of wood types.
Older variable-speed saws allow fine-tuning of blade speed.

I agree. I recently bought an 80-tooth blade for crosscutting oak stair treads. The cut is impossibly clean for being crossgrain, as though by laser, but man do the ends burn.

+1 True. I was planning to get a Bosch tool marketed by some seller online as being suitable for both cutting tiles and wood. But luckily someone cautioned me that tile cutters often have very high rpm (12,000+) which isn't recommended for small circular saws (that rarely require more than 4000 - 5000 rpm unless you are using bigger blades) as they can burn wood due to the friction heat generated by the higher speed.

@isherwood, have you tried leaving a 1/8" to 3/16" of material on the first cut, then cleaning it up to the line with a second pass? I'm curious if not having the additional material to clear or having the waste side of the blade free would make a difference in burning.

Fine tooth blades tend to have a thin kerf compare to rough cut blades.
Thin kerfs might allow the blade body to rub against the wood being cut.  This might cause the burning.
Fine tooth blades cut slower, so much less force should be used when pushing the wood or blade when cutting.  Fine tooth also need more time to clear the chips from the blade, might even need to cut a bit and release before cutting more.  Like a drill bit.
If possible have two saws set up.  One for rough thicker wood and one for fine/delicate cuts.
If not cutting real wood, you are cutting wood and glue/adhesive(particle board/MDF/OSB).  Fine tooth blades might need lubrication(wax) to not gum up.

Going further, the dust from a fine blade behaves differently to chips when it comes to clearing, and heated dust can jam in the teeth.  So frequent backing off of the pressure (cut and release, as in the answer) helps, and if that's not enough, a brass brush across the teeth between cuts or sections of cut. Increased airflow right at the cut will also help with both cooling and dust removal; the narrow kerf makes it both more important and more difficult.
